# how to hide a tree item in the CTreeCtrl?

Tags: mfc

Is it possible to hide an item (and the complete subtree under it) so that the item is actually there in the tree but its invisible.

For example, for the following tree :

```
A
|
|---B
|
|---C
```

I want to hide the item B so that it looks like

```
A
|
|---C
```

Item B is still a child of A but is not visible in the tree.

Is it possible to do so. If yes, how??

note: I can do it by inserting and deleting in tree but in my case this hidding/showing is too frequent hence wants to avoid.

Comment: No, you can't. You must **remove** B to "hide" it and **insert** it again to unhide it.

Comment: No, you cannot hide an item in CTreeCtrl but you can manage it by maintaining a flag (e.g. isHidden) in data structure for each item in the tree. You need to redraw the items in the tree based on the flag.

Comment: What you intend to implement seems an usability disaster to me!